# Is it possible to *partially* claim an iTunes gift card?

Tags: itunes, apple-music, gift

When I claim an iTunes gift card I am given the option to use it toward an Apple Music subscription. For example, I can use a $150 gift card to get a year of Apple Music for $99 and have $51 left over to buy apps or whatever.

But what if I'm not sure yet whether or not I want to commit to the Apple Music Platform? It may not be an obvious decision for everyone. It certainly gave me a pause, while I considered how likely I am to purchase a HomePod in the near future, and various other factors.

Is there a way to claim *just* $51 of the $150 gift card and buy some apps and music while I contemplate whether I actually want Apple Music? Or do I have to buy the Apple Music subscription first, *and then* other iTunes content?

Answer (score 1):

There is a free trial period for Apple Music. Your gift-card will not be claimed within the trial period. Just make sure you cancel your subscription when the free trial ends.

Comment: That's good to know. But do you know if there's a way to start using a gift card for iTunes and App Store purchases and then later use the remaining balance toward an Apple Music subscription?

Comment: @Mentalist I am pretty shure this is possible

Comment: Cool. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Normally the amount of your Gift-Card should add up on your overall iTunes Account balance. So you use how much you like - if you then decide to start with Apple Music the money on the iTunes Account should be used first.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** At the time of this writing **it is *not* possible** to spend part of a gift card credit on iTunes Store content and then use the remaining balance toward Apple Music.

You will be presented with the following screen, where you must choose to either use the credit to get Apple Music now, or use the credit to get only iTunes Store content.

[image: Selection screen (on an iPhone) for choosing how to spend an iTunes gift card credit.]

In my case I chose to put the credit toward only iTunes Store content. I am still considering enrolling in Apple Music sometime in the future with my own funds.

Answer (score 0):

Load the iTunes gift card on to your account, buy the apps and games that you would like but be sure not to spend more than $51 as you will not have enough to buy Apple Music!  And as a side note, the Apple Music free trial is totally worth it!

Comment: Thanks for posting. But what isn't clear is how to use the gift card balance toward Apple Music after choosing to put it toward iTunes Store content. If you know of a way to do that please explain the steps in your answer. I searched "Apple Music" in both iTunes and the App Store, but it did not show up as an item that can be purchased.

Comment: @Mentalist So, if I remember correctly, you recently purchased a $150 iTunes gift card, correct? If that’s the case then I recommend that you load all $150 on to your Apple ID! You can do this by going to the AppStore and sliding all the way to the bottom and clicking redeem! This will put all $150 on your account st once! You can spend it however you wish! As for the Apple Music, there isn’t an app called Apple Music, it’s just called Music! And you need to download that app, open it, make an account, and then determine your subscription (monthly or yearly or student)! Any further questions?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** you can redeem part of an iTunes gift card because I have done this before! **You need to redeem the card through the AppStore that way it is on your Apple ID** I just did it yesterday!